# when use pyspark pandas_udf, python worker use too much memory and exceeding memory limit

Tags: memory, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, user-defined-functions

spark version is 2.4.0, my cluster has four nodes and each node has 16 CPU and 128g RAM.
I am using jupyter-notebook conncet pyspark. The working process is read kudu data by spark then calculate by pandas udf. On the terminal start pyspark

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="/opt/anaconda2/envs/py3/bin/jupyter" PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook" pyspark2 --jars kudu-spark2_2.11-1.7.0-cdh5.15.0.jar 
--conf spark.executor.memory=40g --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=5g --num-executors=4 --executor-cores=8 --conf yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled=false
```

My dataset only 6g and 32 partitions. when running i can see each node has a executor contains 8 python worker and each python worker uses 6g memory!  Container killed by yarn because memory limit.
Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 45.1 GB of 45 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead

I'm confused why does it take up so much memory? data size for each partiton only ~200M. Isn't pandas_udf avoiding serialization and deserialization by pyarrow? Maybe jupyter causes the quesiton?
I am very grateful if anyone helps me.
This is my code.

```
df = spark.range(0, 800000000)
df= df.select("id",rand(seed=10).alias("uniform"),randn(seed=27).alias("normal"),    
randn(seed=27).alias("normal1"),randn(seed=1).alias("normal3")) 
df=df.withColumn("flag",
F.array(
F.lit("0"),
F.lit("1"),
F.lit("2"),
F.lit("3"),
F.lit("4"),
F.lit("5"),
    F.lit("6"),
F.lit("7"),
F.lit("8"),
F.lit("9"),
F.lit("10"),
F.lit("11"),
      F.lit("12"),
F.lit("13"),
F.lit("14"),
F.lit("15"),
F.lit("16"),
F.lit("17"),
      F.lit("18"),
F.lit("19"),
F.lit("20"),
F.lit("21"),
F.lit("22"),
).getItem(
(F.rand()*23).cast("int")
```

)
)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([
StructField("flag", IntegerType()),    
])
@pandas_udf(schema, functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def del_data(data):
    import os
    os.environ["ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT"] = "1"
    return data[["flag"]]
df.groupBy('flag').apply(del_data).write.csv('/tmp/')
```

Comment: Hi there, it would be good to get some more context to the command(s) that were run which might be causing the issue - is there a chance that there is a process which is collecting results on the driver node? What type of pandas_udf are you calling?

Comment: I'm sorry that i didn't see your reply. I've added code.Thank you very much for your help